# Export a global function in webpack.config.js to be used in a typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

New to webpack. I want to export a global function (similar to exporting variables through webpack.EnvironmentPlugin) to be used in a  typescript

I tried something like below just to see the the behavior.

```
module.exports = [{
  ...
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.EnvironmentPlugin({
     env_func: function bindObj() {
        console.log("In plugin");
       }
    })
  ]
}]
```

It gives me an error (as below) when accessed as `envFunc = process.env.env_func; envFunc.bindObj()`

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'bindObj' of undefined

Is there a way or any plugin (similar to EnvironmentPlugin) I can export a function in webpack config that can be used from the typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`webpack.EnvironmentPlugin` is a shorthand notation for [`DefinePlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/) which you can use to define a function. To make Typescript compiler accept it you need to declare the function e.g. include some `.d.ts` file into the project:

```js
xxx.d.ts
--------
declare function bindObj(): void;
declare function fun1(abc: string): number;
```